# Do we exist in warped space and time?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, curvature

Does the Suns altering of space and time (as evidenced at an eclipse) extend to the Earth such that we exist in warped space and time or are we outside those effects.

Answer (score 3):

We are not outside those effects: the Earth orbits the Sun precisely because spacetime is not flat.